# Infinite loop when using spring boot oauth2 client with spring-session xAuthToken session ID resolver

Tags: spring-security, spring-session, spring-authorization-server

I tried to add spring-session with xAuthToken ID resolver to `spring-authorization` [demo client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/demo-client), but after authenticating the user on the OAuth2 server, the browser stuck in an infinite redirection loop. I want to user `x-auth-token` instead of `JSESSIONID`, because I want to consume `demo-clinet` endpoint via @RestController instead of MVC @Controller. Do you know how to use `x-auth-token` instead of `JSESSIONID` in that project?

I've started redis and use spring-session without enabling xAuthToken and all thing works fine, but when I enable xAuthToken by following snippet the browser stuck in infinite redirection loop.

```
    @Bean
    fun sessionResolver(): HttpSessionIdResolver = HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
```

Comment: Please share trace logs (`logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`) of at least one of the requests involved in the redirect loop.

Comment: Actually, I think I know what your issue is so I added an answer. Sadly, I don't believe this will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. I have followed the BFF approach for securing the REST API on a resource server and consuming that API from a native mobile app. However, I have now switched to another approach, which involves using a public client on a native Android app with a PKCE-enabled OAuth2.0 server, without the need for a BFF. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions on this matter.

Comment: "I would greatly appreciate your suggestions on this matter." Apologies, but I'm not clear what you're asking in this case?

Comment: I meant, do you think this approach is good and secure enough?

Comment: In general, I recommend a BFF is used for any public client (SPA, native mobile, tvOS, etc.). Of course, it all depends on your use case. The fact that you're asking about sessions in this question leads me to think you would begin using the OAuth2 access token as a session in the Android app, is that right? If so, I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2 (with the `authorization_code` grant) is a redirect-based (or more generally a browser-based) flow. This means that the browser is used for session management, which also implies cookies. The `HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver` in spring-session works when you have an API client but not when you have a browser client, since the browser doesn't automatically handle the `X-Auth-Token` header in the response, while it does automatically handle `Set-Cookie` headers. So I don't believe there's an easy way to use this session resolution strategy with OAuth2.

Specifically, the issue happens in the first redirect after accessing an unauthenticated page. When writing to the session, the session id won't be remembered by the browser, and every subsequent request is like starting over again, hence the redirect loop.

However, I recently built up a [sample](https://github.com/sjohnr/oauth2-workshop/tree/ojug) that plugs implementations into Spring Security for the `AuthorizationRequestRepository`, `SecurityContextRepository`, and a few others to make a flow like this work. Though it was actually for a reactive client application, so they are reactive implementations instead.